# Cannot add AJAX extender in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I am trying to add a **FilteredTextBoxExtender** in a `textbox` but there's no smart tags from which to choose `Add Extender`. I already removed the ajax toolkit in toolbox and added it again. I tried also to drop the extender into the source view and manually add it to the textbox but still no effect.

Before, there is a smart tag of adding extender but now I can't find it anymore.

What must be the problem on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the extender manually, firstly add the extender and set the `TargetControlID` of extender to the associated texbox, here our associated textbox is e.g `textboxSimple`:

```
<cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender3" runat="server" TargetControlID="textboxSimple">
```

once the `TargetControlID` is set, then navigate to the design mode click on the `textboxSimple` textbox, you will see now the `add extender` and `remove extender` options on it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to page directives..

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

Try downloading a new version of ajax toolkit..I think version of your ajax control toolkit and your application version needs to be same..

Comment: The ajax toolkit version I used Sir is the same with the version of the .net framework I am using. They're both 3.5